Selenium and ChromeDriver - combining devtools session with proxy authentication
I am scraping a cinema website, where I need to use a proxy (which uses authentication) along with chromedriver devtools, because I need to intercept a bearer token.
string uri = "https://somecinema.com";

string scrapingProxy = "https://proxy.someprovider.com:8887";
string scrapingUsername = "myusername";
string scrapingPassword = "mypassword";

var options = new ChromeOptions();

options.AddArgument($"--proxy-server={scrapingProxy}");
options.AddArgument("--ignore-certificate-errors");

var driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

// Create the NetworkAuthenticationHandler with credentials
var networkAuthenticationHandler = new NetworkAuthenticationHandler
{
    UriMatcher = uri => uri.Host.Contains("somecinema.com"), // Only apply for the specific host
    Credentials = new PasswordCredentials(scrapingUsername, scrapingPassword)
};

// Add the authentication credentials to the network request
var networkInterceptor = driver.Manage().Network;
networkInterceptor.AddAuthenticationHandler(networkAuthenticationHandler);
networkInterceptor.StartMonitoring();

string bearerToken = string.Empty;

IDevTools devTools = driver as IDevTools;

DevToolsSession session = devTools.GetDevToolsSession();
FetchAdapter fetchAdapter = session.GetVersionSpecificDomains<OpenQA.Selenium.DevTools.V122.DevToolsSessionDomains>().Fetch;

var enableCommandSettings = new OpenQA.Selenium.DevTools.V122.Fetch.EnableCommandSettings();

var requestPattern = new OpenQA.Selenium.DevTools.V122.Fetch.RequestPattern();
requestPattern.RequestStage = RequestStage.Request;
requestPattern.ResourceType = ResourceType.XHR;

enableCommandSettings.Patterns = new OpenQA.Selenium.DevTools.V122.Fetch.RequestPattern[] { requestPattern };

fetchAdapter.Enable(enableCommandSettings);

EventHandler<OpenQA.Selenium.DevTools.V122.Fetch.RequestPausedEventArgs> requestIntercepted = (sender, e) =>
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(bearerToken) && e.Request.Headers.Any(z => z.Key == "authorization"))
    {
        //Console.WriteLine(e.Request.Url);
        string value = e.Request.Headers["authorization"];
        if (value.StartsWith("Bearer"))
        {
            bearerToken = value.Substring("Bearer ".Length);
        }
    }

    fetchAdapter.ContinueRequest(new ContinueRequestCommandSettings()
    {
        RequestId = e.RequestId
    });
};

fetchAdapter.RequestPaused += requestIntercepted;


driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(uri);

driver.Close();

driver.Dispose();

driver = null;

return bearerToken;


Running JUST the networkAuthenticationHandler bit, which authenticates the proxy, works.

Running JUST the devtools/fetchadapter bits works.

Running both in the same go does NOT work.


If I run the code as above, where the proxy auth is added first, I am prompted for proxy credentials, and the requests are never intercepter.
Q: How can I combine using proxy network auth - AND devtools/request interception?
Ps.I have tried adding username and password to the proxy url and setting the proxy username/pw in the url - it does not work.

I found a solution, got it working.
It seems like  service.HideCommandPromptWindow is key. Does not really make 100% sense to me, but I have fought this issue for months, so I am just relieved it finally works - and I will move on! :)
        string sbUsername = "user";
        string sbPassword = "pass";
        string sbProxyserver = "proxy.someproxy.com";
        int sbHttpPort = 80;
        int sbHttpsPort = 31112;

        string uri = "https://www.somesite.com/";

        var options = new ChromeOptions();

        options.AddHttpProxy(sbProxyserver, sbHttpPort, sbUsername, sbPassword);

        var service = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(); 
        service.HideCommandPromptWindow = true; //THIS IS THE KEY!

        options.AddArgument("--ignore-certificate-errors");
        options.AddArgument("--blink-settings=imagesEnabled=false");

        var driver = new ChromeDriver(service, options); //THIS IS THE KEY!

        driver.Manage().Timeouts().PageLoad = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);

        string bearerToken = string.Empty;

        IDevTools devTools = driver as IDevTools;

        DevToolsSession session = devTools.GetDevToolsSession();
        FetchAdapter fetchAdapter = session.GetVersionSpecificDomains<OpenQA.Selenium.DevTools.V125.DevToolsSessionDomains>().Fetch;

        var enableCommandSettings = new OpenQA.Selenium.DevTools.V125.Fetch.EnableCommandSettings();

        var requestPattern = new OpenQA.Selenium.DevTools.V125.Fetch.RequestPattern();
        requestPattern.RequestStage = RequestStage.Request;
        requestPattern.ResourceType = ResourceType.XHR;

        enableCommandSettings.Patterns = [requestPattern];

        fetchAdapter.Enable(enableCommandSettings);

        EventHandler<OpenQA.Selenium.DevTools.V125.Fetch.RequestPausedEventArgs> requestIntercepted = (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(bearerToken) && e.Request.Headers.Any(z => z.Key == "authorization"))
            {
                string value = e.Request.Headers["authorization"];
                if (value.StartsWith("Bearer"))
                {
                    bearerToken = value.Substring("Bearer ".Length);
                }
            }

            fetchAdapter.ContinueRequest(new ContinueRequestCommandSettings()
            {
                RequestId = e.RequestId
            });
        };

        fetchAdapter.RequestPaused += requestIntercepted;

        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(uri);

        Console.WriteLine("Url loaded");

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(bearerToken))
        {
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("wait completed");


        driver.Close();

        driver.Dispose();

        driver = null;

        Console.WriteLine(bearerToken);


Can you please explain the solution?
And I believe you need to get your 500 bounty points hahah

@amitklein Seems like  service.HideCommandPromptWindow  is the key.  Not really sure why it works, to be honest... ;)

If somebody can explain to me exactly what this does and why it works this way, I am happy to award the bounty to that.

you first need to update chromeDriver Package and Selenium WebDriver to latest one -
OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriverExtensions
Selenium.WebDriver

and try adding this proxy using AddHttpProcy
var options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddHttpProxy("proxy.someprovider.com", 8887, "myusername", "mypassword");

also in  your code replace https:// by http:// in scrapingProxy and try once
